# How to get class of different image in a folder using 'for' loop. I already have a trained model

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, keras

I have a trained model and i want to use this model to predict the class of different images which are kept in a folder. I already tried doing this with a for loop but it is showing me file not found error.

I have already tried doing this with a for loop but it is showing me file not found error. I am using the exact path of the folder location.

```
# image folder
folder_path = '/path/to/folder/'
# path to model
model_path = '/path/to/saved/model.h5'
# dimensions of images
img_width, img_height = 320, 240

# load the trained model
model = load_model(model_path)
model.compile(loss='binary_crossentropy',
              optimizer='rmsprop',
              metrics=['accuracy'])

# load all images into a list
images = []
for img in os.listdir(folder_path):
    img = image.load_img(img, target_size=(img_width, img_height))
    img = img.img_to_array(img)
    img = np.expand_dims(img, axis=0)
    images.append(img)

# stack up images list to pass for prediction
images = np.vstack(images)
classes = model.predict_classes(images, batch_size=10)
print(classes)
```

Expected result- The code should predict to which class images belong to.
Current result- Showing error "File not found" when I run the code, despite using exact path of the folder.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to change for loop to os.walk

```
for root, dirs, files in os.walk(folder_path)
    for filename in files:
        img= os.path.join(root, filename)
```

Comment: Thanks, Amit for the answer. I did the same as you suggested, and now it is showing me this error (AttributeError: 'Image' object has no attribute 'img_to_array')

Comment: It worked.. Thanks. I replaced "img = img.img_to_array(img)" by         "img = image_utils.img_to_array(img)" in the code